# Edit complete HTML of page in Drupal

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-7

We have our site running on Drupal. Now I have 2 landingpages: pages without menu's and a bit different in layout as the others. I want to edit the complete HTML of the pages in the Drupal-interface, so marketeers can easily add HTML-snippets (for testing etc), without using a developer.

How could I create an empty header and footer, and let the complete HTML be the content?

Comment: Is the content a node. Does it have a specific type ? Is the complete html in a WYSIWYG?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a specific node type, and then use this function in your template.php :

```
<?php   
function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{
    if (isset($variables['node']->type))
    {
        $nodetype = $variables['node']->type;
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $nodetype;
    }
}
```

It will allows you to create templates for **pages** (Drupal is only offering this possibility for the page content) based on node types using page--node-type.tpl.php, so that you'll be able to customize the entire page html instead of just the content.